# Send multiple transactions to same address

Tags: ethers.js, polygon

I'm trying to develop an "airdrop" script to transfer matic to a list of eth addresses. However, if the same address occurs in the list I get the RPC error:

> Error: processing response error (body="{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":62,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"already known"}}" ... )

From what I can gather this is because the transaction already exists(?), How can I achieve this? (Assume also that it can be a large list of different addresses, but addresses can appear multiple times).

```js
import {providers, Wallet, utils} from 'ethers'

async function execute() {
  const provider = new providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://polygon-rpc.com')
  const signer = new Wallet('abc...', provider)
  const publicKey = await signer.getAddress()
  const gasPrice = await signer.getGasPrice()
  const gasLimit = '0x100000'

  const recipients = [
    "0xD62791D191A1ADB4DeDef65921c75D6aEbAF0c01",
    "0xD62791D191A1ADB4DeDef65921c75D6aEbAF0c01",
    "0xD62791D191A1ADB4DeDef65921c75D6aEbAF0c01"
  ]

  for (const address of recipients) {
    const tx = {
      from: publicKey,
      to: address,
      value: utils.parseEther('0.001'),
      nonce: await provider.getTransactionCount(publicKey, 'latest'),
      gasLimit: utils.hexlify(gasLimit),
      gasPrice: gasPrice,
    }

    await signer.sendTransaction(tx).then(response => {
      console.log(`TX Hash: ${response.hash}`)
    })
  }

}

execute()
  .then(() => console.log('executed...'))
  .catch(error => console.log('error...', error))
  .finally(() => process.exit(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `for await (const address of recipients)`. My guess is the nonce is being reused for all the transactions hence the same transaction would be detected.

Comment: Yeah this was the case, so I tried incrementing the nonce but eventually hit a new error (something like nonce to low??). What I found was there is an experimental library from Ethers called `NonceManage`, using this to send transactions seems to resolve any nonce issues.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an experimental library called `NonceManager` from Ethers. This seems to resolve the nonce issue as a turn-key solution.

https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/experimental/#experimental-noncemanager

```js
import {providers, Wallet, utils} from 'ethers'
import {NonceManager} from '@ethersproject/experimental'


async function execute() {
  const provider = new providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://polygon-rpc.com')
  const signer = new Wallet('abc...', provider)
  const publicKey = await signer.getAddress()
  const gasPrice = await signer.getGasPrice()
  const gasLimit = '0x100000'

  const recipients = [
    "0xD62791D191A1ADB4DeDef65921c75D6aEbAF0c01",
    "0xD62791D191A1ADB4DeDef65921c75D6aEbAF0c01",
    "0xD62791D191A1ADB4DeDef65921c75D6aEbAF0c01"
  ]

  // Handles the nonce for each transaction
  const manager = new NonceManager(signer)

  for (const address of recipients) {
    const tx = {
      from: publicKey,
      to: address,
      value: utils.parseEther('0.001'),
      nonce: await provider.getTransactionCount(publicKey, 'latest'),
      gasLimit: utils.hexlify(gasLimit),
      gasPrice: gasPrice,
    }

    // Replace signer with nonce manager
    await manager.sendTransaction(tx).then(response => {
      console.log(`TX Hash: ${response.hash}`)
    })
  }

}

execute()
  .then(() => console.log('complete...'))
  .catch(error => console.log('error...', error))
  .finally(() => process.exit(0))
```